# Url redirect adds "localhost" to front of url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My prop `linkUrl` = `www.google.com`

I'm trying to redirect to `www.google.com` with the following code:

`` window.location.href = `${linkUrl}`; ``

and

`` window.open(`${linkUrl}`) ``

However, when I click on the button, I'm redirected to the following URL:

`http://localhost:3000/www.google.com`

For some reason, the code adds `localhost` before the url

Comment: `linkUrl = 'https://www.google.com'`

Comment: You need a protocol, otherwise it's considered a relative URL: `https://www.google.com`

Comment: The code you are showing us should work. Could you show us the relevant parts of your code? (how your button is declared, how your function is called / where it gets the URL from...). Otherwise it's hard to say. My first guess would be that your code is not executed, and something else is handling the click

Answer (score 3):

`www.google.com` is a relative uri, because it doesn't have a scheme. These relative uris are expanded as `http://current-domain/current-path/www.google.com`.

To make this an absolute URI, it needs to look like this:

`https://www.google.com/`